# Installing RVM with space in $USER

Tags: ruby, rvm, osx-mountain-lion

So I've run into a bit of a problem. I've found many similar problems with spaces in $HOME, but the fixes do not apply to spaces in $USER - so I'm posting a question here.

Due to regulations at work my username for my workstation consists of  +space+  (cannot be changed), for instance: John Doe

This is my $USER:

```
$ echo $USER
john doe
```

When I try to install rvm I get the following error:

```
It looks you are one of the happy *space* users(in home dir name),
RVM is not yet fully ready for it, use this trick to fix it:

sudo ln -s "/Users/john doe/.rvm/" /john doe.rvm
echo "export rvm_path=/john doe.rvm" >> "/Users/john doe/.rvmrc"
```

However, when I try to run the first command I get the following error:

```
ln: doe.rvm: No such file or directory
```

And if I attempt to run

```
sudo ln -s "/Users/john doe/.rvm/" "/john doe.rvm"
```

I get:

```
ln: /john doe.rvm: File exists
```

Any help would be **tremendously** appreciated :-)

**Edit**

```
sudo ln -s "/Users/john doe/.rvm/" /john\ doe.rvm
```

yields

```
ln: /john doe.rvm: File exists
```

**Edit 2**

Okay, thanks to **platzhirsch** I no longer get an error message when running the *ln* command. Now the problem is following:

When I run

```
echo "export rvm_path=/john\ doe.rvm" >> "/Users/john doe/.rvmrc"
```

or

```
echo "export rvm_path="/john doe.rvm"" >> "/Users/john doe/.rvmrc"
```

I get the following error when trying to re-install:

```
usage: dirname path
```

**Edit 3**

I've also tried manually editing the .rvmrc file. This is what it looks like:

```
export rvm_path="/john doe.rvm"
```

I've also tried

```
export rvm_path=/john\ doe.rvm
```

With no luck, I still get:

usage: dirname path

When I try to run

```
\curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby
```

Comment: Not sure anymore, the only thing I can think of is to try `echo 'export rvm_path="/john doe.rvm"' >> "/Users/john doe/.rvmrc"` and `echo 'export rvm_path="/john doe.rvm"' >> /Users/john\ doe/.rvmrc`

Comment: If that doesn't work, just do it somehow else. You need to open the path of `/Users/john doe/`, browse it or how else you go into a directory, then look for the `.rvmrc` file, open it and append the line `export rvm_path="/john doe.rvm"`

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't really work either. See the updated question for details.

Comment: Does the path in the `export rvm_path` variable exist?

Comment: Well, the folder '.rvm' in my user folder doesn't exist if that's what you mean - I supposed that would be taken care of by the rvm installer? Should I manually create the .rvm directory before running the installer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this message is fixed with https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues/2140 - just start again and now it will propose the directory with `_` *(underscore)* instead of  *(space)*

Comment: I added a comment at the end of the issue showing how it was solved.

Answer (score 0):

why don't try to escape the white space ?!

```
sudo ln -s "/Users/john\ doe/.rvm/" "/john\ doe.rvm"
```

See this pst about escaping in [linux shell](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/advanced_bash_scripting_guide/escapingsection.html). It is (almost) the same if you are using a terminal on a mac